# running a command on a remote computer using ant sshexec task

Tags: java, ant, ssh

I am new to this subject, Apache Ant, I want to run a command on a remote computer using ant sshexec task. this is part of my undergraduate thesis. I have to solve this problem as soon as possible. there is a target like that :

```
<target id="9" name="connectrun">
<sshexec host="192.168.1.34"
   username="remoteusername"
   password="remotepassword"
   trust="true" 
   verbose="true"
   command="cmd /c dir C:\">
   </sshexec>
</target>
```

I use ant version 1.8.2 and jsch-0.1.48.jar. OSs are windows 7 each of computer. And I turned off windows firewalls When I run the target, I take this error :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:341)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:182)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:223)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:190)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:335)
```

Comment: Have you got an ssh server running on the machine you are trying to connect to?  Try establishing an ssh connection using putty or another ssh client and get that working.

Comment: I have already installed freeSSHd server on my remote windows server. and I have set SSH listening port as 22, this port is default, of course you can change. For other people that want to help about this topic :
http://www.techmalaya.com/2009/08/05/setup-ssh-server-for-windows-freesshd/

Don't forget we will use username and password that created by SSH server. Be careful don't use windows username. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the Java stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This is a generic Java networking error, thrown when it's not possible to make a connection. The typical root cause is when there is no process listening on the remote  side.

Asking a rather obvious question.... Have you installed an SSH server on the remote windows box? Is it listening on port 22?